# MAGENTO 2 - Plugin class... doesn't exist

Tags: magento2

Good evening friends, I am getting an error response while trying to save the products, I tried to clear the cache and do the compilation, but I have the second image as an error response, could you tell me what might be happening?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably some of module is trying to use this. Just run search in your IDE or console:

Do the following:

grep -rnw '/path/to/magentodir/app/' -e 'UpdateLegacyStock'

Also check do you have this plugin in vendor Magento directory.
Magento InventoryCatalog